# Remove vertical jumps from captured VHS video

Tags: vhs, analog, signal-processing

I was watching [the following video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqsZJjqCXlI), and as you can see, the whole frame just jumps up for single frames at random intervals, always to the same height. It seems to me that this would be fairly easy to correct in software, yet my attempts at searching only revealed expensive hardware solutions and claims that this is impossible.

It's easy to imagine a (tedious) workflow in which one manually marks affected frames and enters the vertical offset to shift those frames by, converting a jarring jump to a much-less-irritating flickering out at the top bit of the frame. With modern motion estimation algorithms (or even just detecting a black bar along the bottom of the frame), this process would be trivial to automate. Do such filters exist? Is this actually a common thing and I'm just using the wrong search terms?

I'm curious to watch these videos but I'd like to post-process them with something to make them watchable.